# How do i make this font black in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am just looking for a quick fix how to make this field black . As of right now the CSS makes it `blue` but i want to override it just for this particular field. Here is the `ASP.NET` code.  Not sure where to put a `style` element because it cant go inside a `itemtemplate` tag

```
  <itemtemplate>
      <%# String.Format("{0}", IIf(Request.QueryString("cmp") = Eval("CompanyID"), String.Concat("<strong>", Eval("Lowest_FirstName"), " ", Eval("Lowest_LastName"), "</strong>"), Eval("Lowest_EngineerID")))%>
  </itemtemplate>
```

Comment: Create a SPAN with the text in it. Use CSS - inline or (pref) stylesheet - to style the color of the text of the SPAN.

Comment: i put the span inside the item template but it made the whole column black where should it go

Comment: Just the text to make black (style differently)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do something like this, i.e. wrap the text within the span and set the style property with color.

```
String.Concat("<strong><span style='color:black'>", Eval("Lowest_FirstName"), " ", Eval("Lowest_LastName"), "</span></strong>")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use divs inside Templatefields. 
Example:

```
.testclass {
color: black;
}
 <itemtemplate>
   <div class="testclass"> or <div style="color:black;">
      your code
   </div>
 </itemtemplate>
```